# Help me understand how variables work in Java

Tags: java, scope

I am having problems understanding how private and public variables work.
I am trying to fill the `myStorage.outString` variable from myThread.
But it seems I cannot see the `setInString` method from myThread.
Here is my example:

```
public class CT63_Console extends MIDlet {
    public Storage myStorage;
    public void startApp() {
        this.myStorage = new Storage();
    }
}

public class storage{
    private String[] outString;

    public Storage(){
        AClass myThread = new AClass();
        myThread.start();
    }
    public void setInString(String sendString){
        this.outString = sendString; //push seems not to be supported by MIDP
    }
}

public class AClass{
    public void run(){
        myFunction("write this into Storage var outString");
    }

    private myFunction(myString){
        myStorage.setInString(myString);
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to set the variable and why am I wrong?

Comment: outString is a string array (String[]) while sendString is just a string variable.

Comment: post compiler errors. The other comments are correct, but it sounds like  you might be suggesting something else as well.

Comment: public class storage is with a small s while Storage in CT63_Console is with a big one typo or your actual error?

Comment: Usually I can see which functions are available. But in myFunction I cannot see myStorage at all. Why is this?

Comment: Second, how do I fill outString (being an array), with an additional value in MIDP? What would you suggest to use (I would like to add new values from outside the class and delete one after another (deleting the  olderst first) from inside the class. I want to use a kind of eventlistener. If a new value was added to outString, work with it and if it was successfully send delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `myStorage` without having a reference to it.
You could pass this reference when you create the AClass instance.

Also, you are trying to assign a String to an array of Strings which can't be done.

```
public class Storage{
    private String outString;

    public Storage(){
        AClass myThread = new AClass(this);
        myThread.start();
    }
    public void setInString(String sendString){
        this.outString = sendString; //push seems not to be supported by MIDP
    }
}

public class AClass {
    Storage myStorage;

    public AClass(Storage s) {
        this.myStorage = s;
    }

    public void run(){
        myFunction("write this into Storage var outString");
    }

    private myFunction(String myString) {
        myStorage.setInString(myString);
    }
}
```

Comment: will test it within the next two hours and let you know if this is my missing link ;)

Comment: Perfect: But one more question about this:
`:`How do I fill outString (being an array), with an additional value in MIDP? What would you suggest to use (I would like to add new values from outside the class and delete one after another (deleting the olderst first) from inside the class. I want to use a kind of eventlistener. If a new value was added to outString, work with it and if it was successfully send delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.outString = sendString;
```

`outString` is an array of strings (`String[]`). You cannot assign a single string to an array of strings. So either you need to change the type of that variable to a single string (just `String`), or you need to specify an index where you assign that string to. Note that in the latter case you need to initialize the array first.

Comment: Right: But my question about this: :How do I fill outString (being an array), with an additional value in MIDP? What would you suggest to use (I would like to add new values from outside the class and delete one after another (deleting the olderst first) from inside the class. I want to use a kind of eventlistener. If a new value was added to outString, work with it and if it was successfully send delete it.